# Let a user enter days and times in any time zone, and make sure they get converted from the timezone used to UTC for database storage?

Tags: javascript, laravel, date, time, momentjs

I have a user entering info for a request including a day, a start time, and an end time.

These dates and times are all being entered in a timezone that can change from request to request.

I need to make sure that I am correctly converting the date and times from the current requests's timezone to UTC before storing this in the database.

These values are entered on a frontend (Vue.js) and sent over via an API request to the (PHP / Laravel) backend as a formatted string through moment.js, utilizing moment-timezone as well.

I'm maintaining the front and backend so I can work with either where needed.

From the moment-timezone docs, I see that I can do something like: `moment.tz(myDateString, myTimeZone);` to "Format Dates in Any Timezone"

So say I have the date time `2019-10-22 10:00 AM` and the current timezone `America/New_York`.

I was hoping that doing `var startTime = moment.tz('2019-10-22 10:00 AM', 'America/New_York')` would set me up to be able to just do `startTime.clone().utc().toISOString()` which would give me `2019-10-22 10:00am` 'America/New_York' in UTC but it seems to be off.

My hope was that it would see my initial date, `2019-10-22 10:00 AM`, as being in America/New_York time zone but it seems like it sees the initial date as being in UTC then just offsets it to the America/New_York timezone.

When I run `startTime.format()` I get back `2019-10-22T06:00:00-04:00"` which, if I understand correctly, represents 6am 'America/New_York' timezone and not 10:10am America/New_York timezone like I was hoping.

So, as my question states: I'm looking for the best way to let a user enter days and times in any time zone, and then make sure that gets properly converted from the timezone they used to UTC for database storage?

Comment: ECMAScript Dates are UTC. You can either store the time value (e.g. `date.getTime()`) or an ISO 8601 timestamp with Z offset (as produced by `date.toISOString()`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, and I will provide my solution below.

I think I was overcomplicating things before and it confused me further:

**Preparing and sending API request from frontend to backend:**

If my dateTime is `2019-10-02 10:00 AM EDT (America/New_York)`:

```
const dateTime = moment.tz('2019-10-02 10:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A', 'America/New_York');

const formatted = dateTime.format(); // gives me => "2019-10-02T10:00:00-04:00"
```

I send the const `formatted` (`2019-10-02T10:00:00-04:00`) to my backend.

Before saving in the database I use the `Carbon` library to make sure it is offset to UTC from its current timezone:

```
$dateTime = Carbon::parse($data['date_time'])->tz('UTC')->toDateTimeString();

MyRequest::create([
    'date_time' => $dateTime,
    ...
]);
```

This seems to properly save in UTC in the database as `2019-10-02 14:00:00`.

---

**Followup: Displaying in the dynamic timezone after frontend retrieves the data later:**

```
// incomingDateTime from backend = "2019-10-02 14:00:00"

const dateTime = moment.utc(incomingDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss'); // This is my format in the backend DB.

const dateTimeConverted = dateTime.tz(timezone).format('h:mm A'); // I only want the time here.
```

`dateTimeConverted` will be the time displayed for user in `timezone` used above.